# How to upload file to sharepoint document library

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

can anyone suggest me to create a silver-light sandbox solution on How to upload file to share-point document library.I am C# developer.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the following code:

```
String UploadFile = @"C:\YourFile.txt";
String sharePointWebAdd = "http://yoursite.com/sites/Research/";
String docLib = "Shared Documents";

using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(sharePointWebAdd))
{
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(UploadFile))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", UploadFile);                    

        SPFolder myLibrary = oWeb.Folders[docLib];

        // Prepare to upload
        Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
        String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(UploadFile);
        FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(UploadFile);

        // Upload document
        SPFile spfile = myLibrary.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);

        // Commit 
        myLibrary.Update();
    }
}
```

Also refer to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.aspx

Answer (score 2):

little hard to describe over here. but I assume that You will get [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) from file. for silver light application you need to add two reference dll of client object model.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.dll.
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.Runtime.dll.
```

you can find above dll from `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ClientBin` directory path.

```
 private ClientContext context;
 private Web web;

 private void UploadFile(FileInfo fileToUpload, string libraryTitle, string subfolderPath, bool fileOverwrite)
    {
        try
        {
            //Treatment of files and loading it to byte array []
            Stream str = null;
            Int32 strLen, strRead;

            str = fileToUpload.OpenRead();
            strLen = Convert.ToInt32(str.Length);

            byte[] strArr = new byte[strLen];
            strRead = str.Read(strArr, 0, strLen);

            using (context = new ClientContext("http://localhost/"))
           {
            web = context.Web;

            //Defining where to find the files to tape record the library go
            List destinationList = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryTitle);

            //Creating a file
            var fciFileToUpload = new FileCreationInformation();
            fciFileToUpload.Content = strArr;

            //Must determine whether to upload files directly to the library or whether to upload the files to sub directories and stack your way to the file
            string uploadLocation = fileToUpload.Name;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subfolderPath))
            {
                uploadLocation = string.Format("{0}/{1}", subfolderPath, uploadLocation);
            }
            uploadLocation = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", webUrl, libraryTitle, uploadLocation);

            //Sets the path to the file where you want to upload and subor whether to overwrite the file or not
            fciFileToUpload.Url = uploadLocation;
            fciFileToUpload.Overwrite = fileOverwrite;

            clFileToUpload = destinationList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fciFileToUpload);

            //load web,list.
            context.Load(web);
            context.Load(destinationList, list => list.ItemCount);
            context.Load(clFileToUpload);
            context.Load(clFileToUpload.ListItemAllFields);
            context.ExecuteQueryAsync(OnLoadingSucceeded, OnLoadingFailed);
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            unhideComponents();
        }
    }
    private void OnLoadingSucceeded(Object sender, ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs args)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(fileUploaded); // fileUploaded is function
    }

    private void OnLoadingFailed(object sender, ClientRequestFailedEventArgs args)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(fileNotUploaded); //fileNotUploaded is function
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jigs,thx for reply but I got error saying that "File operation not permitted. Access to path 'C:\aaa\s.txt' is denied."

Comment: it seem to does not have access of directory path. move to file on specific folder in which you have full control access.